# Math Game - How to making 10 Question as a ROUND

Tags: vb.net, math, messagebox

I am making a Math quiz game and I wondering why the question does not change to a NEW ONE when I get the right answer and HOW to make it to 10 and stop running then jump out a message box to ask the user want to PLAY AGAIN or not?

```
Public Class Multiplication
Dim TotalQuestion As Integer
Dim CorrectAnswer As Integer
Dim WrongAnswer As Integer
Dim R As New Random
Dim numOne As Integer = R.Next(0, 10)
Dim numTwo As Integer = R.Next(1, 10)

Dim Ans As Integer = 0
Dim Tries As Integer = 0

Private Sub Multiplication_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Generate()
End Sub

Sub Generate()
    TotalQuestion = TotalQuestion + 1
    Dim Show As String
    Show = numOne & " x " & numTwo & " = "
    lblQuestionMUL.Text = Show
End Sub

Private Function Multiply(ByVal num1 As Integer, ByVal num2 As Integer) As Integer
    Return num1 * num2
    Generate()
End Function

Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Integer.TryParse(lblQuestionMUL.Text, numOne & numTwo)
    Ans = Multiply(numOne, numTwo)
    If Val(txtAnswer.Text) = Ans Then
        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1
    Else
        WrongAnswer = WrongAnswer + 1
    End If
    lblCorrectAns.Text = CorrectAnswer
    lblWrongAns.Text = WrongAnswer
    txtAnswer.Clear()
    txtAnswer.Focus()
    Generate()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In that `Function Multiply` you have code *after* the `Return` statement. That code will not be run because it has already returned away.

Comment: numOne and numTwo are initialized to 2 random numbers. After that they never are changed in your code. That is why it appears the question never changes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous comments you should set the numOne and numTwo variables to random numbers in Generate Sub (Keeping the declaration as Global Variables). Your code just set them in the beginning to random numbers only once. Check the code below:

```
Public Class Multiplication

Dim TotalQuestion As Integer = 0
Dim CorrectAnswer As Integer
Dim WrongAnswer As Integer
Dim R As New Random
Dim NumOne As Integer
Dim NumTwo As Integer
Dim QuizCompleted As Boolean = False

Dim Ans As Integer = 0
Dim Tries As Integer = 0

Private Sub Multiplication_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Generate()

End Sub


Sub Generate()

    If TotalQuestion < 10 Then

        NumOne = R.Next(0, 10)
        NumTwo = R.Next(1, 10)

        TotalQuestion = TotalQuestion + 1
        Dim Show As String
        Show = NumOne & " x " & NumTwo & " = "
        lblQuestionMUL.Text = Show

    Else

        QuizCompleted = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Function Multiply(ByVal num1 As Integer, ByVal num2 As Integer) As Integer

    Generate()
    Return num1 * num2

End Function

Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

    Integer.TryParse(lblQuestionMUL.Text, NumOne & NumTwo)
    Ans = Multiply(NumOne, NumTwo)
    If Val(txtAnswer.Text) = Ans Then
        CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1
    Else
        WrongAnswer = WrongAnswer + 1
    End If
    lblCorrectAns.Text = CorrectAnswer
    lblWrongAns.Text = WrongAnswer
    txtAnswer.Clear()
    txtAnswer.Focus()

    If QuizCompleted Then

        MsgBox("Quiz Completed")

    End If

End Sub
End Class
```